# focusGained and focusLost don't work?

Tags: java, focuslistener

I wanted to make a program that allows the user to add to a file, search for, delete and load from a file animals in a zoo and information about them. So far the buttons delete and search don't work, so pay no attention to them. The problem is that `focusGained` and `focusLost` don't seem to work. I tried every solution I found so far, but I couldn't fix them. So, all help is appreciated. If you have any ideas about how to write the Search and Delete classes, please suggest!

This is the main program:

```
        package GUI_Try;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class GUI_ZOO extends JFrame{

    ArrayList <ANIMAL> animal= new ArrayList<ANIMAL>();
    TextField name,ID,country;
    Button  add = new Button("add"),
            save = new Button("save"),
            //delete = new Button("delete"),
            //search = new Button("search"),
            load = new Button("load");
    String sName="",sID="",sCountry="";
    JPanel pc;
    JScrollPane scrPanName;
    JTextArea text; 


    GUI_ZOO(){
        super("Zoo \"Sofia\" ");
        setBounds(80, 80, 600, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        GUI_DELETE delObj = new GUI_DELETE(); 
        GUI_SEARCH searchObj = new GUI_SEARCH();
        GUI_ADD addObj = new GUI_ADD(sName,name,sID,ID,text,animal,sCountry,country);

        pc = new JPanel();
        pc.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        text = new JTextArea(20,10);

        scrPanName = new JScrollPane(text);

        name = new TextField("Name",15);
        country = new TextField("Country",15);
        ID = new TextField("ID",5);
        text.setEditable(false);

        pc.add(name);
        pc.add(ID);
        pc.add(country);
        pc.add(add);
        pc.add(save);
        pc.add(load);
        pc.add(search);
        pc.add(delete);

        ID.addActionListener(addObj);
        name.addActionListener(addObj);
        country.addActionListener(addObj);
        add.addActionListener(addObj);

        save.addActionListener(new Save());
        load.addActionListener(new Load());
        delete.addActionListener(delObj);
        search.addActionListener(searchObj);

        name.addFocusListener(new Focus()) ;   
        country.addFocusListener(new Focus()) ;  
        ID.addFocusListener(new Focus()) ;  

        add("North",pc);
        add("Center",scrPanName);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class Focus implements FocusListener{

        public void focusGained (FocusEvent e){
            try{
                TextField src = (TextField)e.getSource();
                if(src.getText().equals("Name") ){
                    name.setText("");
                }
                if(src.getText().equals("ID") ){
                    ID.setText("");
                }
                if(src.getText().equals("Country") ){
                    country.setText("");
                }
            }

            catch(ClassCastException ignored){

            }
        }

        public void focusLost (FocusEvent e){
            try{
                TextField src = (TextField)e.getSource();
                if(src.getText().equals("") ){
                    name.setText("Name");
                }
                if(src.getText().equals("") ){
                    ID.setText("ID");
                }
                if(src.getText().equals("") ){
                    country.setText("Country");
                }
            }

            catch(ClassCastException ignored){

            }
        }
    }


            class Save implements ActionListener{
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    try{
                        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("zoo.dat"));
                        os.writeObject(animal);
                        os.close();
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                        System.out.println("Can't save the file zoo.dat");
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex){}
                }
            }

            class Load implements ActionListener{
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    try{
                        ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("zoo.dat"));
                        animal = (ArrayList<ANIMAL>) os.readObject();
                        os.close();
                        text.setText("");
                        for(ANIMAL a:animal){
                            text.append(a.name+"\t"+a.ID+"\t"+a.country+"\n");
                        }
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                        System.out.println("Can't find the file zoo.dat");
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();//?
                    } 
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();//?
                    }
                }
            }

            public static void main(String arg[]){
                new GUI_ZOO();
            }
        }
```

I divided the program, so the class GUI_ADD would be here:

```
 package GUI_Try;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI_ADD implements ActionListener{

    String sNamel;
    TextField namel;
    String sIDl;
    TextField IDl;
    String sCountryl;
    TextField countryl;
    JTextArea textl;
    ArrayList <ANIMAL> animall;

    public GUI_ADD(String sName,TextField name,String sNumber,TextField ID,
            JTextArea text,ArrayList <ANIMAL> animal,String sCountry,TextField country){

        sNamel = sName;
        sCountryl = sCountry;
        IDl = ID;
        namel = name;
        sIDl = sNumber;
        countryl = country;
        textl = text;
        animall = animal;
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        sNamel=namel.getText(); 
        sIDl=IDl.getText();
        sCountryl=countryl.getText();
        if((sNamel.length()==0)||(sNamel=="Name")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Type a name, please.");
            return;
        }
        if(sIDl.length()==0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Type an ID, please.");
            return;
        }
        if(sCountryl.length()==0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Type a country of origin, please.");
            return;
        }
        animall.add(new ANIMAL(sNamel,sIDl,sCountryl));
        textl.append(sNamel+"\t"+sIDl+"\t"+sCountryl+"\n");
        namel.setText("");
        IDl.setText("");
        countryl.setText("");
    }
}
```

And this is the interface:

```
    package GUI_Try;

    import java.io.*;

    class ANIMAL implements Serializable {
        String name, ID, country;
        public ANIMAL(String name, String ID, String country){
            this.name = name;
            this.ID = ID;
            this.country = country;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Also, learn how to create a [mcve] ... if you don't need people to look at the "search" or "delete" buttons, why include them in the question? Instead, remove them from the code, to make the question smaller, and easier to understand and help with.

Comment: Why are you mixing AWT and Swing?  If you are intending on creating a Swing program, don't use `Button` and `TextField`, use `JButton` and `JTextField`.

Comment: Do not change the whole question because answer become irrelevant. Instead ask a new question

Comment: You are right, I will. Thank you.

Comment: why ignore Exceptions? I would reject any program when I see `catch(ClassCastException ignored) { }` (Sure there are one or two Exceptions that could be ignored in very special occasions... but NEVER if the program is not working!) at least add `ex.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Thank you, I will add it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You donot need to `implements` `FocusListener` in both classes. Its redundant here.

```
public class GUI_ZOO extends JFrame implements FocusListener{

class Focus implements FocusListener{
```

**And the reason for `FocusGained` and `FocusLost` did not work:**

```
TextField name,ID,country;
```

You have used `java.awt.TextField`,

```
JTextField src = (JTextField)e.getSource();
```

But you are trying to get source from `JTextField`. In your program you donot have any `JTextField`'s right!.

Change it to:

```
TextField src = (TextField)e.getSource();
```

Comment: I can't believe I omitted something so simple. Thank you! Do you have any suggestions about how to build the Search and Delete methods? Tutorials, sites, ideas, anything is appreciated. :)

Comment: From what are you going to search? `name` ?

Comment: I wanted to search for either a name, a country or an ID. So far I only came up with using the if statements in the `Add` class to check if the user has entered the input correctly, than use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` to print out all of the data corresponding to their search ( for example, there could be 4 lions from different countries).

Next, I was thinking about using the same ifs for the Delete class, but after I check the input, I wanted to create a temporary `JTextArea` where I store all lines not containing the input. What do you think?

Comment: I wanted to add that the user should be able to delete animals by their ID. What do you think would work here? `public boolean remove(Object o)` ?

Comment: Its better if you can ask new question clearly mentioning what you have tried because I cannot completely understand and too broad it is too broad. Please ask a question clearly mentioning problem and code for `search` and `delete`

Comment: I apologize for not giving you a "I accept this answer badge". I made sure I did now. Thank you again for the help and have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (one of many) is mixing AWT and Swing components.

You create name, ID, and country as `TextField`, and then try to cast them as `JTextField` in your `Focus` listener.  But, you protect against a `ClassCastException`, by suppressing it, so you don't even see evidence of this problem anymore.

```
try {
    JTextField src = (JTextField) e.getSource();
    // ... omitted
} catch(ClassCastException ignored) {
    // No-op
}
```

You want (*need*) to use `JTextField` and `JButton` Swing objects, not the AWT objects, in your Swing program.

An additional problem with your `focusLost` method.  If the the `JTextField` that loses focus is blank, you will overwrite your `name`, `ID` and `country` text fields ... not just the blank ones!

Comment: Thank you for the help. How do you suggest I should change the FocusLost method in order to fix the second problem?

Comment: @BeowulfDragonheart Change things like `if(src.getText().equals("") ){ name.setText("Name"); } ` to `if(name.getText().equals("") ){ name.setText("Name"); } ` (as in `src` to `name`)

Comment: Thank you. Would you explain to me why `src` doesn't work as expected here?

Comment: If your name input contains "Lion" and ID contains "123" and the country input loses focus while empty, then `src.getText()` will equal "", so the `name` input is set to "Name", the ID input is set to "ID", then country is set to "Country".  You've lost "LION" and "123"

Comment: I see. I think I managed to fix the mistake. Thank you again for all the help! Cheers! :)